# _getAsyncTracker() returns error: undefined is not a function

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use the GA tracker object to push external links to GA for tracking.  However, I am not sure how to get past this weird error when creating the tracker.  From what I can tell, I am doing the same thing that many examples have.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because the function `_getAsyncTracker()` is not defined yet. The reason it's not defined yet is because your code is running before the ga.js script is finished downloading.

What you need to do is wait until the script has downloaded, and then you can run your code. You can do that by pushing a function onto the `_gaq` array. Once ga.js is downloaded, it'll execute your function.

```
_gaq.push(function() {
  var tracker = _gaq._getAsyncTracker();
  console.log(tracker);
});
```

Also, beware that the `_getAsyncTracker()` method is deprecated:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq#_gaq._getAsyncTracker

Answer (score 0):

Moving the errored line of code out of that script block into another one gets rid of the error.  Not sure why though.